# How to use a different file when the file does not exist in Synapse serverless SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure

I want to use a query that uses another file if that file does not exist.
I ran the following query in Synapse's Serverless SQL and got an error.

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://dls001dev.dfs.core.windows.net/published/test/year=2023/month=05/test05.parquet',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://dls001dev.dfs.core.windows.net/published/test/year=2023/month=04/test04.parquet',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
END CATCH
```

And error message is here.

```
File 'https://dls001dev.dfs.core.windows.net/published/test/year=2023/month=05/test05.parquet' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.
```

It is true that 'https://dls001dev.dfs.core.windows.net/published/test/year=2023/month=05/test05.parquet'
does not exist, but instead of returning an error in this case, we would like to use 'https://dls001dev.dfs.core.windows.net/published/test/year=2023/month=04/test04.parquet'
instead of returning an error in this case.

Comment: On Microsoft SQL Server the `TRY-CATCH` blocks only work for runtime errors. The problem here is that the access to the `BULK` file path is being evaluated at statement compile time, errors, and doesn't get caught by the runtime error handling. Have you tried this: create a stored procedure that invokes your `OPENROWSET(BULK...)` statement as dynamic SQL via `sp_executesql`. When you `EXEC` the wrapping stored procedure with an invalid/inaccessible filepath and the caller can capture it in its own  `TRY-CATCH` block. Actually, even simpler... try using `sp_executesql` in-situ.

Answer (score 0):

- As commented by **@AlwaysLearning**, using the query directly inside the try-catch block is giving error anyway. As suggested, using dynamic query `EXEC` or `sp_executesql` returned the required result.
- I got the same error when I have tried the following similar query as yours:

[image]

- Updating the query as follows helped in getting the desired result.

```
BEGIN TRY
    exec('SELECT * 
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(
        BULK ''https://datalk100523.dfs.core.windows.net/data/sample2.csv'',
        FORMAT = ''CSV'',
        PARSER_VERSION = ''2.0'',
        HEADER_ROW = TRUE) AS [result]');
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
exec('SELECT * 
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(
        BULK ''https://datalk100523.dfs.core.windows.net/data/sample1.csv'',
        FORMAT = ''CSV'',
        PARSER_VERSION = ''2.0'',
        HEADER_ROW = TRUE) AS [result]');
END CATCH
```

[image]

- The following query also returns the same result which uses `sp_executesql`.

```
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);  
SET @SQLString =  
     N'SELECT * 
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(
        BULK ''https://datalk100523.dfs.core.windows.net/data/sample2.csv'',
        FORMAT = ''CSV'',
        PARSER_VERSION = ''2.0'',
        HEADER_ROW = TRUE) AS [result]';  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;  
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SET @SQLString =  
     N'SELECT * 
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(
        BULK ''https://datalk100523.dfs.core.windows.net/data/sample1.csv'',
        FORMAT = ''CSV'',
        PARSER_VERSION = ''2.0'',
        HEADER_ROW = TRUE) AS [result]';  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;  
END CATCH
```